# Is the value of i defined after: int i, j = 1;

Tags: c++

Given:

```
int i, j = 1;
```

Is the value of `i` defined? If so, what is it?

<sup>I suspect this is a duplicate, but it's somewhat hard to search for - if anyone can find it let me know.</sup>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Global variables are initialized by
  default to their default values (0
  for int)
- Local variables are not initialized
  by default

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

int a, b=1; // a=0, b=1

int main(void) {
 int p, q=1; // p=undef, q=1
 return 0;
}
```

proof for local variables:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void) {
  {
    int x = 99; // change stack where a would be
  }
  int a, b=0;
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for identifying that i *will* be defined if it has file scope.

Answer (score 5):

If this code is in global scope, then `i` will be 0. Otherwise `i` is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

If this is defining local variables then the value of `i` won't be defined.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not defined, and the compiler should complain if you try to use it, depending on the language.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice.
I think it depends on the compiler -- the Windows DDK compiler right now gave me a warning, but it really depends on the compiler.

Comment: The two compilers I've tried don't always complain (try using it in the third bit of a `for` statement - `for (;;++i)`)

Comment: Windows DDK compiler:

`temp.cpp(4) : warning C4700: local variable 'i' used without having been initialized`

Comment: Probably because of your assertion that the compiler should complain. There is no such requirement that I can see. (And the language is C++ given the OP's tag).

Comment: I said the compiler *should* complain, not that it must. :) A good compiler would complain, a mediocre one wouldn't. I guess I can see the other reason... though I'd say it's a little harsh. Oh well. :)

Answer (score 1):

The code you showed is equivalent to:

```
int i;
int j = 1;
```

that means, that `i` is defined, but not initialized.

Comment: I think that defined and initialized is generally considered to mean the same thing, i.e. referring to the value of the variable. To be clear: the variable is declared, but it's value is not defined or initialized.

Comment: The Standard says: 'A declaration may introduce one or more names into a translation unit...' (see 3.1.1, [basic.def]), while 'A declaration is a definition unless ... it contains the extern specifier ... and no initializer ...' (see 3.1.2, [basic.def]). That means `int i;` is a definition (no `extern`). Declaring, defining, and initializing a variable are three different things.

Answer (score 1):

`i` will be undefined. This leads to undefined behaviour if you try to use `i` without assigning it something.

Any good compiler will warn you about stuff like this. Using an undefined variable of type `int` might be harmless enough, but don't use undefined pointers.

Perhaps not today, but some time ago, before sufficient hardware and software protection, you could damage your machine's BIOS by using pointers with uninitialized variables.

Moral of the story: if it isn't initialized, don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

`int i` is a definition statement, but it is not assigned with a value.

`Extern int i` is declaration.

Comment: i is not defined, but declared.

Comment: @Mihran please check this link http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/658832-difference-between-declaration-definition-variable  thay have specified ..and also in some text books they have specified like that..if im wrong i will update my self thanks anyway..

Answer (score 0):

The variable i can contain anything from 0 to garbage.
please refer to the following link

http://www.intap.net/~drw/cpp/cpp03_02.htm for more information